# How to use C++/CLI to program Winforms applications

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Is there a pdf or video or some media that can inform me on how to program Winforms with C++. Obviously C++ is the most common programming language and I already have some prior knowledge. But when I try to find media about programming in C++, the examples are usually Console applications. I want some media that can teach me how to program Winforms in C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a tutorial showing how to write [Windows Forms applications in C++/CLI](http://www.functionx.com/vccli/general/introprogramming.htm).

Just be aware that most samples tend to be in C#.  Many people purposely use C# for the forms, C++ for their logic, and use C++/CLI to expose their logic as .NET assemblies (For easy use by C#/VB.NET).  This helps, since the design-time experience is much nicer in C# or VB.NET for Windows Forms.

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea, IMHO. Managed C++ is ugly; it was never meant to be a garbage-collected language. Its strength lies elsewhere. I recommend C# instead - similar syntax, highly marketable skill.

Preemtive snarky comment: all C++ is ugly.

Comment: Managed C++ is ugly - C++/CLI is much nicer, though.  There's nothing wrong with doing Windows Forms from C++/CLI  (WPF, though, is VERY tough in C++...)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s69bf10x%28VS.80%29.aspx) [articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x5ewhf3%28VS.80%29.aspx)? I'm not saying I recommend this, but they do at least give a start.

As far as Seva Alekseyev's comment that all C++ is ugly: it's like the old comment about democracy being the worst form of government except for all the others. He's right that all C++ is ugly, but fails to mention that all the alternatives are even worse.

Comment: Don't get me wrong - I've used C++ for 12+ years, and I generally like it. Just making that comment before someone else does.

Now let's all get together, sing kumbayah and flame on Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new C++ .NET project and start programming your C++. And additional syntax applies to .NET is managed pointers and .NET classes. Information about them you can find in MSDN, including lots of useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are opinions all over the place on this topic. My motto is always to use the right size hammer for the job-- and, in general, C++ is the wrong size hammer for making winforms. I love C++, but I only use it when there is an absolute necessity for speed of operations.

C# (or VB.Net, if you must) has MUCH better support for UI creation than C++, though I have noticed that Visual Studio 2010 offers some much needed enhancements to make developing Winforms easier in .NET 4.0. If you MUST stick with C++, look into obtaining a beta version of Visual Studio 2010. Otherwise, use C# as your UI, data access, file manipulation, general purpose language and C++ if you have to write a custom physics engine to go with it.