# Visual IDE with WinForms for C?

Tags: c, ide

Background:
I worked a lot with C#.Net in the last years (Visual Studio).
At the moment I am on a project for iPhones, I use the iTunes MobileDevice.dll and have a lot of reference code in C.

I try to give my best to do it in C#.Net but I give up now and like to change to C.

So I will now rebuild my C#.Net Code, its a WinForm Project with a lots of events and so on.

Now I search the best IDE, I tried Eclipse but as far as I see there is no WinForm Visual-thing I can use, or? Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as WinForms for C, nothing even close as far as I know.

However, [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) might be what you are looking for.  Because it is c++ it can easily interoperate with C libraries, and because it is also .Net is can interoperate with .Net libraries (like those that comprise WinForms).

Some other Stackoverflow questions have addressed this and their answers are informative:

[How to use C++/CLI to program Winforms applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009326/how-to-use-c-cli-to-program-winforms-applications)

[Can I use C++/CLI (.NET Winforms/WPF ) to provide GUI for app written in native C & C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2778621/can-i-use-c-cli-net-winforms-wpf-to-provide-gui-for-app-written-in-native-c)

If you go the C++/CLI route, Visual Studio will likely be the best visual IDE.